# C'è qualche differenza tra "attirare" e "attrarre"?

Tags: word-usage, verbs, difference

C'è una differenza tra i verbi *attirare* e *attrarre*? Esempi:

> Sembra una cosa che potrebbe ***attirare*** le persone sbagliate...
>
> Sembra una cosa che potrebbe ***attrarre*** le persone sbagliate...

Tutte e due le parole si traducono in inglese con "attract". Sono sinonimi?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Come mostra la risposta di Abarisone, nell'italiano contemporaneo “attrarre” e “attirare” sono sinonimi. Complementarmente a quella risposta voglio segnalare che storicamente “attirare” si è diffuso dopo “attrarre” e che nell'Ottocento era percepito come un francesismo da evitare nel senso di “richiamare l'attenzione”, mentre non era proprio usato nel senso fisico (in cui si usava invece “attrarre” o “trarre”).

Scrive Niccolò Tommaseo nel suo dizionario dei sinonimi (5ª edizione, del 1867):

> *Tirare, Attirare, Attrarre, Chiamare*
>   *Attirare* è adoperato da qualche scrittore, non però dal popolo toscano, ch'io sappia; e risica di parere gallicismo, ancorché abbia forme analoghe italiane. Senonché quasi sempre *attrarre*, *trarre*, *tirare* ne fanno le veci, senza ch'esso nulla aggiunga a evidenza, e non certamente a eleganza. D'oggetto che volge a sé il senso o la mente con più o meno soavità, basta *attrarre*; se con più forza, *trarre*; se con ancor più, *tirare*. Ma i due ultimi, secondo i luoghi, denotano più o men vigore, e possono altresì denotare soavità, forza il primo. ...
>   Se mai volesse adoprarsi *attirare*, non so s'io sbagli, ma direi che meno si disconvenga all'animo che al senso o alla mente. Chi poi dice: attirare gente o simile, non veggo perché non possa *tirare* o *chiamare* secondo che più o meno potente è l'allettamento o l'invito.

Nelle voci del Tommaseo su “attrarre” e “tirare” riferito a calamite e simili, “attirare” non è contemplato.

In varie altre voci sullo stesso insieme di verbi Tommaseo esamina anche la distinzione, collegata a quella della presente domanda, fra “tirare” e “trarre” (accennata anche nel brano riportato), rimproverando alla Crusca il fatto che tratta insieme i due verbi. Per esempio:

> ... L'affetto gentile trae, la passione tiranna tira. L'eloquenza sincera trae, la retorica vuol tirare, e comincia dallo stiracchiare sé stessa.

Answer (score 2):

Può essere utile confrontare il significato dei termini su Treccani:

> [attrarre](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/attrarre/) (ant. attràere) v. tr. [dal lat. attrahĕre, comp. di ad-
>   e trahĕre «tirare»] (coniug. come trarre). – 1. a. Attirare, tirare a
>   sé: la calamita attrae il ferro; anche in senso astratto: a. l’occhio,
>   la mente, l’attenzione, la simpatia.
>
> [attirare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/attirare/) v. tr. [der. di tirare]. – Trarre a sé: la calamita
>   attira il ferro. Molto com. con sign. più generico (cfr. attrarre): la
>   bellezza del paesaggio attira molti forestieri; a. i clienti con la
>   pubblicità; a. qualcuno in un tranello; a. i nemici in un’imboscata.

Il termine “attirare” deriva da “tirare” che deriva a sua volta da “[lat. *tirare, di etimo incerto]” (Treccani), mentre “(at)trarre” deriva appunto da trahĕre (in lat. trahĕre).

Il dizionario dei sinonimi e contrari di Treccani a proposito riporta:

> [attrarre](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/attrarre_(Sinonimi-e-Contrari)) v. tr. [dal lat. attrahĕre, der. di trahĕre "tirare",
>   col pref. ad-] (coniug. come trarre). - 1. [tirare a sé: la calamita
>   attrae il ferro] ≈ e ↔ [→ ATTIRARE (1)]. 2. (fig.) [richiamare
>   l'attenzione] ≈ e ↔ [→ ATTIRARE (2)].
>
> [attirare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/attirare_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/) v. tr. [der. di tirare]. - 1. [trarre a sé: la calamita
>   attira il ferro] ≈ attrarre, calamitare. ↔ respingere. 2. (fig.)
>   [richiamare l'attenzione] ≈ attrarre,

Come si può vedere *attirare* ed *attrarre*, almeno nell'italiano contemporaneo, possono essere considerati sinonimi.

Addirittura il de Mauro usa lo stesso esempio per entrambe le varianti:

[Attrarre](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/attrarre)

> 1. di sostanze, attirare, tirare a sé: *la calamita attrae il ferro*

[Attirare](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/attirare)

> 1. di sostanze, tirare a sé, trarre a sé: *la calamita attira il ferro*

Comment: “Come si può vedere derivano entrambi da tirare (in lat. trahĕre)”: Scusa la pignoleria, ma “attirare” deriva da “tirare” che deriva a sua volta da “[lat. _*tirare_, di etimo incerto]” (Treccani), mentre “(at)trarre” deriva appunto da _trahĕre_.

Comment: @DaG grazie per la precisazione

Comment: @DaG Ho inserito la tua precisazione nella mia risposta.